# NamingException getting when tried to push the message to Activemq

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jndi, messaging

i tried to publish message to activemq.but i am getting one naming exception in my java application. here is the code follows

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
    props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"tcp://localhost:61616");
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
     // get the initial context
     // InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
     QueueConnectionFactory connFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("ConnectionFactory");        
     // create a queue connection
       QueueConnection queueConn = connFactory.createQueueConnection();                                                       
       // lookup the queue object
       Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("nixon");
```

i am getting three warning plus below one error like this

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: nixon
at org.apache.activemq.jndi.ReadOnlyContext.lookup(ReadOnlyContext.java:235)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at com.youtube.rest2.status.ProducerNewClient.main(ProducerNewClient.java:38)
```

can anyone tell why i am getting this error..?

Comment: It clearly says its not able to lookup nixon queue. Is the queue setup ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely getting this error because you haven't configured the destinations in you JNDI configuration file.  You can either add these definitions to your file or use the dynamic destination features of ActiveMQ.

For the easiest possible configuration with JNDI based programs, there are 2 dynamic contexts as follows

```
dynamicQueues
dynamicTopics
```

which allows you to lookup queues and topics using JNDI without any configuration.

e.g. if you use the following name to lookup into JNDI
dynamicQueues/FOO.BAR

you will get back an ActiveMQQueue of the name "FOO.BAR".

Read the [JNDI Documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html) at the ActiveMQ site for more.